# T-SQL Recursion; Multiple Recursions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion, recursive-query

I'm trying to conceptualize a solution to a problem I have with recursion and I can't quite wrap my mind around it. I have three tables. We'll call them `DocGroup`, `GroupGroup`, and `GroupUser`. In the `DocGroup` table there is a hirerachial structure of one record, which specifies another record as it's parent and so on until a record is its own parent.

```
Doc Group
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   2
6   4
```

`GroupGroup` contains Group nesting:

```
Group    MemberGroup
4        2
4        1
```

`GroupUser` maps a group to a number of users:

```
Group    User   Key
1        1      ABC
1        3      BCD
1        4      CDE
2        1      DEF
2        2      EFG
2        3      FGH
3        3      GHI
4        2      HIJ
4        3      IJK
4        4      JKL
```

So I would like to specify a user and a document and get a list of all the keys for that combination. For example if I choose user 2 and document 2 I need to return "EFG" but if I choose document 6 and user 3 I need to return "IJK", "GHI", "FGH", and "BCD" because group 2 and 1 are in group 4 and group 4 = document 4, which has a group of 3. In all cases I only need to get the record for the specified user.

I would imagine that I need multiple recursions to get this done, but I can't seem to mentally map out how that might be done in SQL and I don't want to degrade to loops and cursors to do this.

Comment: Why do you say that `group 4 = document 4` ?

Comment: @ypercube, because in the first table there is a hierachy, and `Group` references `Document` in all cases, but not all `Documents` have a child specified in another record in the `Group` field.

Comment: Can you clarify your statement that `group 4 = document 4`?  Are you saying the `Group` Column on the `GroupGroup` table is really a `Doc` value?

Comment: So, the `6 4` record in first table, says that Doc-6 is in Group-4 ?

Comment: If that is the case, and all documents are also groups, why do you need 2 hierarchies? Remove the `Group` column from first table and add those relations `Doc - Group` to the second table.

Comment: Yeah, i'm calling data architecture shenanigans.  At the very least, you need to rename your columns to something meaningful.

Comment: Hm, on second thought, this design makes some sense (in a very complicated scenario). I'll call the `Doc-Group` nesting "Green nesting" and the `Group-MemebrGroup` one "Red nesting". What I guess you want is for a given User, find all related Groups (using the 3rd table). Then, using the "Red" nesting, find all parent (and parent-parent, etc) Groups of those related Groups. Then using "Green" nesting, find all Children (and Grandchildren, etc) of those ParentGroups. So, to go from a UserGroup to a Doc, you use Red and Green paths but Red to go only Up and Green to only go Down. Is that right?

Comment: (and once you step into a Green path, you can't use a Red any more.)

Comment: @ypercube, I'm not entirely sure what you are saying with red and green here. Basically, the first table is the hierarchy of documents. Some documents are also groups. The second table is a hierarchy of groups. The third table is a mapping of users to groups. A group's definition is stored as a document entry. A document can only belong to one group, but it can have multiple users. To simplify administration, the `Group-MemberGroup` table was added to allow groups to be nested.

Comment: To *"simplify administration"* Since you already have an hierarchy of documents (which some of them are groups), why do you need a second hierarchy?

Comment: @ypercube, If each document can only belong to one group, what is the easiest way to add 1000 users to a document? I wouldn't want to add them to a single group and have to do that for 1000s of documents. Instead I add them to a group once and then add a group to a group; thus the GroupGroup table. --I actually have found the answer, but I can't post it for another 6 hours. Thanks for all your help.--

Comment: I should clarify my above statement. I can add 1000s of documents to a single group, but what if I have a subset of 100 users that need to be in a bunch of different groups (think management). I would just add their group to another group instead of adding all 100 to each group they needed to be a part of. This also simplifies changing that group of 100 as I would only have to change it once instead of every group they appear in.

Comment: @cjbarth - Was a somewhat lame and predictable recursion "joke". Now deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is the answer:

```
DECLARE @Key varchar(max)

;WITH DocBase AS (
    SELECT Doc, Group
        FROM DocGroup
        WHERE Doc = @Doc
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DocGroup.Doc, DocGroup.Group
        FROM DocGroup INNER JOIN DocBase
            ON DocGroup.Doc = DocBase.Group
        WHERE DocBase.Doc <> DocBase.Group --to prevent infinite recursion
    ), GroupNesting AS (
    SELECT Doc
        FROM DocBase
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MemberGroup
        FROM GroupGroup.Group = GroupNesting.Doc
    ), GroupList AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Doc
        FROM GroupNesting
    ), KeyList AS (
    SELECT Key
        FROM GroupList INNER JOIN GroupUser
            ON GroupList.Doc = GroupUser.Group
        WHERE User = @User
    )
SELECT @Key = COALESE(@Key, '') + Key
    FROM Key

SELECT @Key
```

I could have used any of the suggestions from http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ for doing the final concatenation, but I chose this method because it is the easiest and I'm putting this in a procedure anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have to post this because I'm a raging egomanic:

[The Zen of Recursion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496042%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

But seriously, that's how we did it back in the day. These days, you'd use a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

HTH.

Comment: I've used CTE before and I'm sure I'll have to use them to solve this problem, but how? That article looks interesting BTW.